# Calling obj.i18.pluck in a model with a jsonb backend gives a TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

I'm using Mobility 0.8.4 and when I try to pluck an attribute from a model, it raises a TypeError.

```
# models/skill.rb
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility

  translates :name, backend: :jsonb
end

# db/schema.rb
create_table "skills" do |t|
  ...
  t.jsonb "name", default: {}
  ...
end
```

Then...

```
irb(main):001:0> Skill.pluck(:name).take(5)
   (1.9ms)  SELECT "skills"."name" FROM "skills"
=> [{"pt-BR"=>"Ruby"}, {"pt-BR"=>"Java"}, {"pt-BR"=>"PHP"}, {"pt-BR"=>"Python"}, {"pt-BR"=>"C++"}]

irb(main):002:0> Skill.i18.pluck(:name).take(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Mobility::Arel::Nodes::Jsonb into String)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bug, it was fixed in 0.8.7: https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/releases/tag/v0.8.7

Answer (score 0):

`i18` wants to translate strings but you're feeding it JSONB. Try:

```
Skill.i18.pluck("name -> 'pt-BR'").take(5)
```

That should pluck the value of the key `pt-BR` (e.g., `Ruby`, `Java`, etc.) and feed it through the i18 translator, rather than supplying the full JSONB payload to the translator.

Comment: Sounds weird. The purpose of Mobility  is to automate fetching some values related to a locale instead. Under the i18 scope it is possible to execute `where(name: 'Java')` with the JSONB backend translating it to the proper JSON query. Also, as of 0.8.2 there is support for pluck, select and group and as far as I understand, these should reproduce the behavior of `where()`